# Spectral theorem and projection

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

This should be simple, but I'm stuck.
Let $A$ be an unbounded self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $H$. The spectral theorem says that there is a decomposition of $H$ into a direct sum for which $A$ is unitarily equivalent to the multiplication operator by the identity function on each component of this direct sum:
$$(UAU^{-1}f)_n(x)=xf_n(x)$$
where $n$ is the index of the component.
Now let $P$ be the orthogonal projection onto $\ker(A-a)$ for some isolated point $a$ in the spectrum of $A$. I would like to show, by only referring to this version of the spectral theorem, or else to functional calculus, that:
$$(UPU^{-1}f)_n(x)=1_{\{a\}}(x)f_n(x)$$
where $1_{\{a\}}$ is the characteristic set function of $\{a\}$. I'm getting a little confused and would appreciate some help...

Comment: $a \in H$? or $a$ in the spectrum of $A$? Is it an isolated point in the spectrum?

Comment: It is indeed isolated in the example I am looking at. I raised the question in more generality, but that might be a bad idea. I'll change the text.

Comment: There's nothing to show. It's just the statement of the Borel functional calculus. The spectral measure has an atom, if you'd like, at $\{a\}$. $1_{a}(A)$ is the projection onto the corresponding eigenspace.

Comment: Clarification: since you're taking into account multiplicities, $1_{\{a\}}$ is the projection onto a one-dimensional summand that is a one-dimensional subspace of the eigenspace corresponding to $a$.

Comment: @Michael: I can see that it has the properties of a projection, but not why it is the projection onto that particular eigenspace...

Comment: Try considering the finite dimensional case.